# How can I escape the vertical bar when doing command line with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd

I have this command line input in Windows:

```
dir /b | ruby -ne 'f=$_.chomp;File.read(f).each_line{|line| print f if line =~ /helloworld/};'
```

This line is to find all files under current directory with `helloworld` in it. (I understand there are many other ways to do this but the post is not focusing on that)

My question is:

This line gives error saying `line is not a valid command`. Then I realized `|` in Ruby as a brace for block variable is a pipe sign in cmd. I tried to change the whole line into double quoted and escape the | sign but no success. How can I escape the vertical bar |?

**Please don't answer other ways to do the task such as using other tools like grep, find, sed or awk, or change the block into for loop.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found [this microsoft.com page](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) that says the following about pipes and special characters:

> The ampersand (&), pipe (|), and parentheses ( ) are special
>   characters that must be preceded by the escape character (^) or
>   quotation marks when you pass them as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes seem to be your problem. Use double quotes instead, because they're required for Windows (though Unix can understand either).

This works for me in Windows:

```
C:\tmp\ruby>echo helloworld > foo.txt

C:\tmp\ruby>dir /b | ruby -ne "f=$_.chomp;File.read(f).each_line{|line| print f if line =~ /helloworld/};"
foo.txt
```

I know you mentioned that you tried double quotes, but if you paste what you actually tried, I can see if something else was wrong.

Comment: It actually works! I did try, but only tried with | escaped by \ but did not try it without escaping anything, and this turned out to be surprisingly good.

Comment: @texasbruce Glad to hear it. That's one of the realities of programming - you also have to understand a good deal of the workings of the OS. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting.