# Ruby one-line script execution returns an error (on Windows)

Tags: ruby, windows

EDIT: I found an identical question that has been answered: [How can I escape the vertical bar when doing command line with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644837/how-can-i-escape-the-vertical-bar-when-doing-command-line-with-ruby)

I have `my.rb` file containing only one line:

```
File.popen("myprocess.exe","w"){|file| file.puts "help"; file.puts "quit";}
```

that I can execute via `ruby my.rb` and it works like a charm. However, if I try to run the following command:

```
ruby -e 'File.popen("myprocess.exe","w"){|file| file.puts "help"; file.puts "quit";}'
```

it complains that *"file" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*. Trying to simplify it further, the following line still returns the error:

```
ruby -e 'File.popen("myprocess.exe","w"){|file|}'
```

And this code works fine:

```
ruby -e 'File.popen("myprocess.exe","w"){}'
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Does the Windows shell treat `|` as a special character even within strings? It looks like this is the case, as the command is being interpreted as `ruby -e 'File.popen("myprocess.exe","w"){'` being piped to `file`. Maybe instead of `ruby -e` try `echo`.

Comment: what terminal setup are you running on windows?

Comment: @tadman: thank you for the idea! I searched in this direction and found a very similar question with an answer

Comment: Good catch! I had a quick look but couldn't find anything.